# How to dynamically pass degree of parallelism in create statement in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to pass degree of parallelism dynamically. For example, in below code, I have hardcoded the passed degree of parallelism to 8 but I want to parameterize it. Is there a way to do that?

Sample Code:

```
CREATE TABLE ABC NOLOGGING PARALLEL 8 AS
SELECT * FROM XYZ
;
```

Comment: your question is not understandable.

Comment: Everything else in the CREATE TABLE statement is hardcoded. So what  value do you hope to gain from setting the DOP dynamically?

Comment: @APC: It's probably a result of simplification for the sake of question clarity. The real query is probably much more complex.

Comment: @hilarion - maybe you're right, maybe you're wrong. Either way the question needs clarification before we can answer it sensibly.

Answer (score 2):

Bind variables are generally not supported for DDL. The most common method is to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, i.e.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE ABC NOLOGGING PARALLEL ' ||
  my_parallel_degree_constant ||
  ' AS SELECT * FROM XYZ';
```

Comment: it worked perfectly.Thanks a lot.Below is my working code                                      set serveroutput on;
declare
my_parallel_degree_constant number;
v_sql varchar2(4000);
begin
v_sql:= 'CREATE TABLE ABC NOLOGGING PARALLEL ' ||
  &my_parallel_degree_constant ||
  ' AS SELECT * FROM XYZ';
 dbms_output.put_line(v_sql); 
 execute immediate v_sql;
  end;

Comment: Great! If it worked, please accept the answer as well.